# Fixnum / String等を arrayに包んで返すメソッドってありますか？？

Tags: ruby

```
class Object
  def with_bracket
    [self] unless self.is_a?(Array)
  end
end
```

みたいなメソッドです。

```
[1,2].with_bracket.each do |i|
end
1.with_bracket.each do |i|
end
```

みたいに使いたいです。
(Objectクラスに書くか迷っていますが、with_bracketの命名も募集していますｗ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array()` というメソッドがあります。

```
Array(1)      #=> [1]
Array("abc")  #=> ["abc"]
Array([1, 2]) #=> [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Fixnum / String` と想定されているので、問題ないかもしれませんが、Hash などでは想定外になるかもしれないので、少しだけフォローを

```
[5] pry(main)> Array({a: 1, b: 2})
=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
```

`[{a: 1, b: 2}]` にはならないので、知っておかれると宜しいかと思います。

> arg に to_ary, to_a のいずれのメソッドも定義されていない場合は 一要素の配列 [arg] を返します。
>   [module function Kernel.#Array (Ruby 2.2.0)](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Kernel/m/Array.html)

activesupport が使えるなら、wrap をお勧めします。

```
Array(foo: :bar)      # => [[:foo, :bar]]
Array.wrap(foo: :bar) # => [{:foo=>:bar}]
```

[wrap (Array) - APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/wrap/class)